# Why is this string matching my regEx?

Tags: php, regex

I'm sorry for just another regEx question but even after reading two online tutorials and using three online regex testern I still don't understand why some of my teststrings match my regEx.

I want to achieve that:

- the first character of a string only contains of letters or a digit
- the following characters contain letters, digits, minus (`-`), underscore (`_`), space (), pipe (`|`)
- the whole string is between 3 and 30 characters long

So I wrote this regEx: `[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\| ]{2,29}`

In my understanding this means that the string must start with one character (`{1}`) which is a letter or digit (`[a-zA-Z0-9]` or alternatively `\w`) and the following two to 29 characters (`{2,29}`) may also contain the characters mentioned above.

When testing the regEx with online tools (e.g. http://www.phpliveregex.com/ ) and the following test strings I got the following result

```
+--------+----------+--------+
| String | Expected | Actual |
+--------+----------+--------+
| T_2    | OK       | OK     |
| This   | OK       | OK     |
| -bla   | NOK      | OK     |
| _bla   | NOK      | OK     |
| 0|This | OK       | OK     |
+--------+----------+--------+
```

I don't understand why the strings `-bla` and `_bla` match the regex as they don't start with a digit or letter.

Can please anyone explain me this and show me my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `^` symbol in the start of your regex, to point out it is the start of the string:

`^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\| ]{2,29}`

The `^` means "The string will start with the expression follows the `^`. If you dont put it, the whole expression will match anywhere in the string (as it doesn't have a start point). So, for example, the `bla` will be matched in `_bla` - and you get a match you didn't want.

[Here is a working example](https://regex101.com/r/msSeie/3)

Comment: So I was close, damn. I'll accept in five minutes as SO doesn't allow me to do this yet.

Comment: Thanks, if you would like, [read more about the caret in regex](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html#caret)